# How to work around wildcard inside double quotes?

Tags: bash, quoting, wildcards

In bash, the file globbing * doesn't work inside double quotes, but my filename contains whitespace, so I need to double quote filename before passing it to a shell script. How can I do that?

For example

```
myscript.sh "0$i*.pdf"
```

where the pdf files may be "01a b.pdf", "02c d.pdf". I use `i` to store `1` and then `2`.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes it answer my question? Or does you understand my question?

Comment: "You can interpolate globbing with double-quoted strings", i.e., `myscript.sh "0$i"*".pdf"`.

Comment: What is my question?

Comment: @Tim, I believe your question is clear enough and also I believe that Quasimodo's comments are exactly to the point. Could you please try the command he suggested in above comment and tell us if it works for you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply unquote the glob.

```
myscript.sh "0$i"*".pdf"
```

It seems you are worried that `*` would expand to a string containing whitespace,  `b`? That is no problem, after pathname expansion (as known as globbing), whitespace loses its syntatical value and becomes literal.

See a sample execution:

```
$ ls -1
'01a b.pdf'
'01e f.pdf'
'02c d.pdf'
myscript.sh

$ cat myscript.sh
#!/bin/sh
for file in "$@"; do
    echo "$file"
done

$ i=1

$ ./myscript.sh "0$i"*".pdf"
01a b.pdf
01e f.pdf
```